# Keyword not supported on sqlconnection string query

Tags: c#, keyword

I need your help (eyes) to see where am I wrong here.

So, I'm having this error...

[image]

Here's what I'm doing...

A Logged In User, has a Role which has some permissions or not.

When he enters a form, the application checks for User permissions based on his Role. In this case, it checks for Navigation permissions and disabled the "Add New" button which disallow user to add new data.

I must say that this query or similar, works very well in other situations, and compiled into SQL Query, it return the value 0 or 1 correctly.

And here's the code in the Load Form.

```
Extensions.UserInfo.ActiveButtons(Extensions.UserInfo.CurrentLoggedUser);
```

The ActiveButtons is an static method which disables specific button, based on Logged In User...

```
public static bool ActiveButtons(string user)
    {
        if (CanNavigate(CurrentLoggedUser) == true)
        {
            foreach (var button in Buttons)
            {
                if(button.Name == "novoToolStripMenuItem")
                {
                    button.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    button.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var button in Buttons)
            {
                button.Visible = false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The CanNavigate method, checks for permission on Role Table. Her's the code...

```
public static bool CanNavigate(string user)
    {
        bool result;
        string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
        string query = "SELECT tblRole.Navigate FROM tblRole INNER JOIN tblUser ON tblRole.RoleID = tblUser.RoleID WHERE tblUser.Username = @Username";
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(query.ToString()))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user);
                result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

And, has you see, the error is in this method on query SqlConnection...

So, what's wrong with it?

On Debug, the user is getting the correct CurrentLoggedUser!

Thanks.

Comment: The `SqlConnection` constructor expects a connection-string, not a SQL query. You just need to swap `str` and `query.ToString()`.

Comment: You're trying to put your select statement in as the connection string...

Comment: Constructor of `SqlConnection` takes connection string as argument not the sql query and you are passing `SELECT` sql query there. That's why you are getting this error. You should pass `str` in `SqlConnection` and `query` in `SqlCommand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably swapped the `str` and `query` variables .

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(str))        
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
```

looks a lot more plausible

Comment: Of course! Sometimes the answer is right in front of us. We make it complicated! Thanks a lot. Maybe I need some sleep!